# neokrees Navigation Drawer doesn't show up

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

As a newbie in Android programming I'm playing with some Material Design. So I wanted to implement a Navigation Drawer. After looking for libraries I decided to use @neokrees MaterialNavigationDrawer (https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer). I added it into my build.gradle and followed the instructions from the wiki.
As a base I'm using a MainActivity which holds a toolbar and a fragment.
I created a custom style for the drawer and wrote a simple NavigationDrawer subclass.

```
import it.neokree.materialnavigationdrawer.MaterialNavigationDrawer;

public class NavigationDrawer extends MaterialNavigationDrawer {

    @Override
    public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.addSection(newSection("Section", new MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment()));
    }

}
```

Then I added this to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".NavigationDrawer"android:theme="@style/MyNavigationDrawerTheme" />
```

So everything compiles fine, the app starts up but nothing happens. So as first try I added a section to the drawer, relating to an activity. As I saw that the first item should be a fragment, I replaced it accordingly. Then I looked into the example app, but I don't get it to compile. Anyway, there is also no drawer-relevant code in the MainActivity.

So it's most probably a really dumb failure, but I have no idea anymore. So I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Why dont you make copy of given demo project and edit it as you want!

Comment: I tried, but the demo is a fairly complex project and I have problems compiling it after importing into Android Studio. It seems they're not using Gradle as build system and in the moment I'm not experienced enough to get it to run.

Comment: Wait have you called oncreate()? followed [Steps](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer/wiki/Set-Up-a-Navigation-Drawer-Activity)?

Comment: I created a NavigationDrawer object in my Oncreate() in the MainActivity and saved it into a static var. The init() function is called definitely.